# order by clause not working after shrinking database

Tags: sql-server-2008

Recently, I have shrink local database and size reduced from 6gb to 1 mb.

But after that some query doesn't work, those are already working in development and live server (in local, development and live sql version is same).

One of this query is

```
SELECT a.col1,
       b.col2,
       isnull(a.intPriority, 100) AS intPriority
FROM   tab1 a
       INNER JOIN tab2 b
         ON a.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT a.col1,
       b.col2,
       isnull(a.intPriority, 100) AS intPriority
FROM   tab1 a
       INNER JOIN tab2 b
         ON a.id = b.id
ORDER  BY a.intPriority
```

This query giving me an error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Above query runs well in dev and live server, why not on local??

I know, suppose I changed order by to intPriority than problem will solved but its not solution. I have to change in my entire website.

Comment: Why are you doing a union here? Since both statements are the same and union filters out duplicates, all you are accomplishing is to make the query slower.

Comment: Also you might tell use what database version is running on the machine that doesn't work and the ones that supposedly do. (I find to hard to believe that any do actually work as that is a basic syntax error.)

Comment: It's example. In my case, i've another query on right side of union.

Comment: So can you show us your **actual** code then? Also what compatibility level are all the database versions set to?

Comment: If your "entire website" contains invalid syntax, why don't you want to fix it?

Comment: There is a quote in ["Behavior Changes to Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2005"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143359(v=sql.90).aspx) that might be relevant In 2000 `Column names in the ORDER BY clause are resolved to columns listed in the select list, regardless if they are qualified... SQL Server ignores the qualifier a in the ORDER BY clause`. I don't have 2000 around to test.

Comment: Yes, @MartinSmith, that works fine in SQL Server 2000 (just tested). So maybe a piece of information that is missing is that the OP shrunk the database *and* upgraded from SQL Server 2000. I've updated my answer to show that setting compat level to 80 can be a patch in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need:

```
ORDER BY intPriority
```

Also I don't think this has anything at all to do with shrinking your database, but perhaps you upgraded from SQL Server 2000 as well? If so you can "get by" in the meantime by rolling your compat level back to 2000. Just to demonstrate, on SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT name = COALESCE(a.name, '') FROM sys.objects AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT name = COALESCE(a.name, '') FROM sys.objects AS a
ORDER BY a.name;
```

Fails with:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

But works after setting:

```
ALTER DATABASE my_db SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80;
```

So you can set the compat level for your database back to 2000, and your invalid code will work in the meantime, but you really should FIX it, because eventually 80 won't be a valid compatibility level (it is no longer valid in SQL Server 2012) and because someone else might upgrade the compatibility level on the servers where this is already working (since this is typically one of the [recommended steps after upgrading a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15857/upgrade-process-from-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012)).

Comment: I agree, I can't see any way this should have worked at all. ON any machine.

Comment: that i know. but before shrinking db i've taken db back up and this query works on this..

Comment: **Not** a response to your previous comment! Not mine. Your demo code does not demonstrate the issue it has no `ORDER BY`. This does `SELECT name as foo from sys.objects a union SELECT name as foo from sys.objects a ORDER BY thisIsNonsense.foo`

Comment: @Martin thanks, my copy+paste between guest and host is hosed, bad transcription.